# What does , char *(*g(char a, int b)) mean?

Tags: c

What does the following declaration mean?

```
char *(*g(char a, int b))
```

So far, I know that,

```
char *(*g)(char, int)
```

declares a pointer to a function that returns a `char *`, and I can successfully assign a value to it, however I can't do the same with the first. Any hints?

Comment: This just has extra `()` around `*g`. The code is the same as without them.

Comment: This looks pretty much as if intention was just to confuse others -> code obfuscation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a function `g` that takes two arguments (`char a` and `int b`) and returns `char**`.

The outer parenthesis looks working like ones in `char** x = /* some value */; char y = *(*x);`

As a proof, this code compiles:

```
char *(*g(char a, int b));

char** test(void) {
    return g(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Identical as typing, `char **g(char, int);`

Answer (score 2):

The two lines of code in the question are very different:

```
char *(*g(char a, int b))  // #1

char *(*g)(char, int)      // #2
```

In #2 you have added a `)` just after the `g` and that really changes the meaning a lot.

The first one is simply a function with the name `g`. It's the same as

```
char **g(char a, int b)   // #1 without the unnecessary ( ) pair
```

but number two is a **function pointer** variable with the name `g`.

That also explains why you can assign to `g` in case #2 but can't assign to `g` in case #1.

Also notice that #1 is a function returning **pointer-to-pointer-to-char** while #2 is a function-pointer to a function returning **pointer-to-char**

So the two lines of code are different in more than one aspect.

Answer (score 1):

What does , `char *(*g(char a, int b))` mean?

[g as function (char, int) returning pointer to pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*%28*g%28char+%2C+int+%29%29)

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
char *(*g)(char, int);
```

**g** is a pointer to a function...

Is you've got several functions taking a character and an integer for parameters and returning a 'char *' you can assign either of these functions to this pointer..

Example :

```
char *function1(char c, int i) {
   ...
}

char *function2(char c, int i) {
...
}
```

when you declare a pointer like you can see below, it can point on either of the above functions :

```
char *(*g)(char, int);
```

You can write:

```
g = function1 ;
```

or:

```
g = function2 ;
```

And when you call the function using the pointer:

```
char *retVal = (*g)('a', 12) ;
```

It will call either function1 or function2 depending on the last function that was assigned to the pointer.

As for :

```
char *(*g(char a, int b))
```

This is equivalent to :

```
char **g(char a, int b)
```

considering operator () has precedence level 1 and operator * has precedence level 2, the parenthesis doesn't affect the evaluation order.